# How to replace ASCII Text with Hex Value

Tags: android, hex, ascii, str-replace

I have a string

`msg = "Hello.. welcome. Your ID is 'abcd' & pwd is '123' !!";`

I'm replacing the white spaces with

`msg = msg.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20");`

Result is

`msg = "Hello..%20welcome.%20Your%20id%20is%20'abcd'%20&%20pwd%20is%20'123'!!`

How to replace the  ASCII Text like (**&**, **'** , **"** , **!**) etc with Hex Value.

which results in a string like

```
msg = "Hello..%20welcome.%20Your%20id%20is%20%27abcd%27%20%26%20pwd%20is%20%27123%27%21%21
```

Comment: hey check my answer and tell me is it solved your problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "utf-8").replace("+", "%20");
```

**EDIT**

This is a better way.

```
String url = Uri.parse(msg)
                .buildUpon()
                .build()
                .toString();
```

Comment: Log: `query﹕ Hello..+welcome.+Your+ID+is+%27abcd%27+%26+pwd+is+%27123%27+%21%21` whitespaces are not replaced

Comment: @KNeerajLal Will this add a new line? i mean `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Try this class

```
public class EncodingDecodingUtil {
    private final static String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    private static final String TAG = EncodingDecodingUtil.class.getName();

    /**
     * This method Encode String to UTF -8
     *
     * @param stringToEncode
     * @return return Decoded String Or Same String if exception
     */
    public static String encodeString(String stringToEncode) {
        String encodedString = null;
        Logger.e("before encoding", stringToEncode);
        try {
            encodedString = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, UTF_8).replace("+", "%20");
            ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "String encoding" + e);
        }

        if (encodedString == null) {
            return stringToEncode;
        }
        Logger.e("after encoding", encodedString);

        return encodedString;
    }


    /**
     * This method decode String from UTF -8
     *
     * @param stringToEncode
     * @return return Decoded String Or Same String if exception
     */
    public static String decodeString(String stringToDecode) {
        String decodedString = null;
        try {
            decodedString = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(stringToDecode, UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "String decoding" + e);
        }

        if (decodedString == null) {
            return stringToDecode;
        }
        Logger.e("after decoding", decodedString);
        return decodedString;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
String decodedMsg = EncodingDecodingUtil.decodeString(msg);

String encodedMsg = EncodingDecodingUtil.encodeString(msg);
```

Comment: OMG.. O.O Never thought that string replacement may need 1 class 2 methods

Comment: @Prabs i suggested this so that you can use it as a utility class

Comment: Sorry @Harsh but I'm really lazy to try a utility class and may be it is not a good practice to utilize processor time in executing these classes and methods for a string replacement. Do you think it is a better option?

Comment: @Prabs it is better if and only if your project needs this kind of task(Encoding Decoding) at many places

Comment: I respect your effort to solve the thing. I prefer the accepted answer